# Display Selected Dropdown Value As List

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in React JS. I followed tutorial and tried to create a project when user selects the dropdown value and the selected value concatenates to a list. I got error message on the this.setState and had no clue how to solve the problem. Can someone give me a direction? Many thanks!

**App.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Institution from "./Institution/Institution";
import InstitutionList from "./InstitutionList/InstitutionList";
const institutions = [
  { id: "School1", value: 4000, key: 1 },
  { id: "School2", value: 3800, key: 2 },
  { id: "School3", value: 3850, key: 3 }
];
const selectedList = [];

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      InstitutionList: []
    };
  }

  _handleSelect(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //create an object
    const institution = {
      id: event.target.id,
      value: event.target.value,
      key: event.target.key
    };

    //add school to selectedList
    this.setState({
      selectedList: [this.state.selectedList.concat(institution)]
      // selectedVal: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form>
          Select a school:
          <select onChange={this._handleSelect.bind(this)}>
            <option>Select</option>
            <option>School1</option>
            <option>Schoo2</option>
            <option>School3</option>
          </select>
        </form>
        <p>
          <InstitutionList selectedList={selectedList} />
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Institution.js**

```js
import React from "react";

const Institution = props => {
  return (
    <div className="Institution">
      <p>Name: {props.id} </p>
      <p>
        Tuition:
        {props.value}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Institution;
```

**InstitutionList.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import Institution from "../Institution/Institution";
const InstitutionList = props => {
  return props.selectedList.map(institution => {
    return (
      <Institution
        key={institution.key}
        id={institution.id}
        value={institution.value}
      />
    );
  });
};

export default InstitutionList;
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: TypeError: this is undefined. When the onChange calls this.setState

Comment: updated code:_handleSelect(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //create an object
    const institution={
      id:event.target.id,
      value:event.target.value,
      key:event.target.key
    };
   
    //call add institution to institutionsbox
   
   this.setState((state) => ({
    selectedList: [...this.state.selectedList].concat(institution)
  }));
  } and new error message "TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you run it the `this.state.selectedList` does not exist in the state, as your initial state only contains `InstitutionList`. So the `this.state.selectedList.concat` will fail because you try to call `concat` on an `undefined` object.

Also your `selectedList: [this.state.selectedList.concat(institution)]` will keep nesting arrays arrays. You most likely need

```
selectedList: [...this.state.selectedList].concat(institution)
```

Additionally, when modifying state based on the previous one, it is suggested to pass the function version (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

So

```
this.setState((state) = > ({
      selectedList: [...state.selectedList, institution]
    }));
```

and you can fix the first issue at the same time by using

```
this.setState((state) = > ({
      selectedList: [...(state.selectedList || []), institution]
    }));
```

Comment: thanks. how to pass the selected value (as object) to the function?

Comment: @user788448, expanded my answer with more info that fix the problem.

Comment: @user788448 also, do you want to selected multiple schools or just one ?

Comment: I changed to this.setState((state) = > ({
      selectedList: [...state.selectedList, institution]
    })); and still receive the same error. Is it possible the selected instituion object didn't get passed to the function from onChange? Thanks.

Comment: Never mind. The error message was fixed after adding .bind(this) to <select onChange={this._handleSelect.bind(this)}>. But the selectedList does not display anything in   <p>
          <InstitutionList selectedList={selectedList} />
        </p>

Comment: @user788448 it is not clear from your code what you are trying to do. For example you have a `InstitutionList` item in your state which you do not use anywhere..

Comment: InstitutionList is a function (component) that I want to display for all selected value in the dropdown box. So this project I want to create two compontents: Institution and InstitutionList under App.js. Thanks.

Comment: I mean the `InstitutionList` in `this.state = {InstitutionList: []};` in the constructor.

Comment: I changed it to selectedList.

Comment: @user788448 see https://codesandbox.io/s/l753204v5m for a working example

Comment: Thank you so much! My problem is  to set the initial state in the _handlerSelect function. const selection = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex];
    if (selection.value === "0") return;
    const institution = {
      id: selection.id,
      value: selection.value,
      key: selection.key
    };

Answer (score 0):

Below is revised code for App.js. When I select the dropdown value,  does not display in the render. No error message right now.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Institution from './Institution/Institution';
import InstitutionList from './InstitutionList/InstitutionList';
const  institutions=[ 
{id:'School1', value:4000, key:1},
{id:'School2', value:3800, key:2},
{id: 'School3', value:3850,key:3}
];
const selectedList=[];
class App extends Component {

constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
  selectedList:[]

  };
}


 _handleSelect(event){
 event.preventDefault();
//create an object
 const institution={
  id:event.target.id,
  value:event.target.value,
  key:event.target.key
};

//call add institution to institutionsbox

 this.setState((state) => ({
 selectedList: [...state.selectedList].concat(institution)
}));
}
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">

    <form>

         Select a school:
         <select onChange={this._handleSelect.bind(this)} >
           <option>Select</option>
           {institutions.map((institution)=>{return (<option value={institution.key}>{institution.id}</option>);})}


         </select>

         </form>
      <p>Display <InstitutionList  selectedList={selectedList} /></p>

  </div>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: the revised code does not show error but it does not display selected value as expected. Please help!